# Unexpected output while printing 2 array (matrix)

Tags: arrays, c, loops

**output is printing only few elements of matrix that to in a wrong order**
*i think something is wrong with the printing loop but unable to figure it out*

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int x=0, y=0;
    int a[x][y];
    printf("enter the number of rows in first matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("enter the number of columns in first matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    printf("enter elements of first matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        {
            printf("enter element %d %d\n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < x; p++)
    {
        for (int q = 0; q < y; q++)
        {
            printf("%d\t", a[p][q]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, why do you name your loop variables `p` and `q` (or `i` and `j`) and not better `row` and `col`, so you know what are your printing exactly?  Not only your code will be more maintainable and readable, but you will probably see what you are doing.

Comment: @LuisColorado Actually, yeah  its really good to understand and visualize things much better . Thankyou for the advice. But u need a good IDE LIKE VS CODE so that the defined variable suggestions enable us to write quicker.

Comment: yes, but the problem is not writeability, but readability, as the code normally must not only be written, but also it needs to be maintained (sometimes by some different person)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're declaring the matrix before receiving the size of the matrix (you're variables x and y). In your code, the matrix is declared as a[0][0].

Solution:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    printf("enter the number of rows in first matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("enter the number of columns in first matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    int a[x][y];
    printf("enter elements of first matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("enter element %d %d\n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < x; p++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < y; q++) {
            printf("%d\t", a[p][q]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: but if i didnt do that , then the program stops at input , try running once with and without initialising x and y with 0

Comment: Yes, you have to have the input of the x and y before initializing a[x][y].

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing your 2d array with 0 rows and 0 columns.
You need to move `int a[x][y]` down under `scanf("%d", &y);`

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    printf("enter the number of rows in first matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &x);
    printf("enter the number of columns in first matrix:\n");
    scanf("%d", &y);
    int a[x][y];
    printf("enter elements of first matrix\n");
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            printf("enter element %d %d\n", i, j);
            scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    for (int p = 0; p < x; p++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < y; q++) {
            printf("%d\t", a[p][q]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```